# DNS server request pattern optimization

Tags: domain-name-system

In a specific setup (Specific Website) DNS server is getting request for specific record (www.example.com) thus it's confident that the request will be followed by series of others (x.example.com, y.example.com, z.example.com).

Is it possible to gain reduction in these other requests if their RRs are included in additional section of DNS response (preemptive responding)? I.e.

```
DNS QUERY
  www A

ANSWERS
  www A IN 11.22.33.44

AUTHORITATIVE NAMESERVERS
  NS IN ns1
  NS IN ns2

ADDITIONAL RECORDS
  x   A IN 55.66.77.88
  y   A IN 99.11.22.33
  z   A IN 44.55.66.77
```

The intention is to use such pre-populated responses:

1. to speed up overall interaction with domain DNS server is serving (primary objective).
2. to reduce DNS server load (secondary objective).

Is there any DNS service provider that is expert in this type of optimizations? Or let me know about argumented write-up on the topic and why the above is not possible.

Comment: Can you be specific about your specific setup and specific record? It's pretty hard to help if you're not specific.

Comment: Seconding @voretaq7's comment about details.  Usually in DNS land the round trip time itself and the TTL are the biggest things(read: several orders of magnitude) you can use to improve performance.  You don't mention why those won't help or what you've already done there.

Comment: This is explicitly tying the DNS protocol to HTTP-only?

Comment: Sorry I do not know what HTTP-only DNS protocol is ;)

And yes, the question above is about DNS working to help HTTP client have less questions to DNS, preferably single request and sigle response containing all information HTTP client will need in future.

Comment: I've updated question with specific details.

Comment: Even if you can get your server to do this, the intermediate caching servers won't do as you wish.  Most requests should be resolved from caching servers, so your load is likely to significantly lower than the web servers.

Comment: @BillThor: cache helps for repeating requests, and does nothing for initial ones. If caching servers (located closer to visitors) would accept and cache records from Additional Records section but fail to relay the original jumbo response  - that would be fine, as RTT from client to caching server is usually by order smaller then RTT to authoritative DNS.

Answer (score 0):

It can never be confident of others. For example:

website http://www.test.com/index.html (test.com is lookup one, then www.test.com is #2)
has 20 images, all hosted on different sites.

DNS can not predict this without loading the HTML first, but thats what the client is for. The client's browser will decode the HTML and request all the sources to the images, usually all at once.

What if the page changes and they update all the links of images?

BL: It's never going to be able to PREDICT dns requests, but it CAN cache prevoius requests.

The TTL of the record (expiration time) will let the DNS server when to purge that record from the cache.

That's just about it.

Comment: Controlling the test.com and index.html is the key. The question is not about PREDICTION, but about KNOWLEDGE, what requests follow the initial one. If one knows what is request pattern, can one pack as many responses in initial answer?

Comment: I've updated question with specific details. DNS server is not expected to be "intellectual". I just want to inject x, y, and z records whenever there is request for www record.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without custom dns software. I mean, if it was, everybody would be doing this. Sorry.

Comment: Is this just round robin?

Comment: The x, y, and z RRs are different names and different IPs. They represent addresses of subdomains hosting resources for the webpages hosted on primary www sobdomain.

I understand that it is very custom, and requesting to point me into direction of DNS provider that does that or does not, and explains why it is not possible.

Comment: This: "I understand that it is very custom, and requesting to point me into direction of DNS provider that does that or does not, and explains why it is not possible." is not a complete thought.

Comment: I understand that the requested functionality is very custom. Thus I'm requesting to point me into direction of DNS provider that provides the functionality requested. Alternatively I'd like to read write-up that the requested functionality is not possible with explanation why it is not.